# have to make connection between a field and single selection in oracle adf

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracla adf and javadeveloper.
I drag table view from data controls into jsf page as table and  drag another table view from data controls into this jsf page as single selection .
I want to know is any way that a field that I created respond to single selection. for example when I select a value from single selection, that field display the selected value from single selection ?

Answer (score 0):

User, tell us your Jdev version, please!

Yes it's possible. Ask you have to do is to open the data control, there you open the bio you used to drag onto the page single selection. Select the attribute from the vo you want your variable to reflect and drag it to the field. Now the field I'd bound to the attribute currently selected row attribute.